# Having a conditon on every array element that's a part of an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Just need to bring up an condition where I need to display a block based on the condition if its true or not

I have an array with following structure

```
const data = [
  { name: "item1" , values : [0,0,0,0,0]},
  { name: "item2" , values : [0,0,0,0,0]},
  { name: "item3" , values : [0,0,0,0,0]}
] // return false

const data = [
  { name: "item1" , values : [0,0,0,0,0]},
  { name: "item2" , values : [0,1,0,0,0]},
  { name: "item3" , values : [0,0,0,0,0]}
] // return true
```

Basically I need to have a check in such a way that if all entries inside "values" in each object is 0 then return false. If any of the entries inside "values" is other than 0 return true;

Have tried something like this. But does not seem like working

```
const isZero= (currentValue) => currentValue === 0;
console.log(data.every(isZero));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the array and `values`.

```js
const check = array => array.some(({ values }) => values.some(Boolean));

console.log(check([{ name: "item1", values: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, { name: "item2", values: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, { name: "item3", values: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }])); // return false
console.log(check([{ name: "item1", values: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, { name: "item2", values: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] }, { name: "item3", values: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }])); // return true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `.some` data object has `.some` values properties that are not `0`:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "item1" , values : [0,0,0,0,0]},
  { name: "item2" , values : [0,0,0,0,0]},
  { name: "item3" , values : [0,0,0,0,0]}
] // return false

const data2 = [
  { name: "item1" , values : [0,0,0,0,0]},
  { name: "item2" , values : [0,1,0,0,0]},
  { name: "item3" , values : [0,0,0,0,0]}
] // return true


const verify = data => data.some(({ values }) => values.some(num => num !== 0));
console.log(
  verify(data),
  verify(data2)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could apply `some` to `data`, going through all the items, and use `some` again on each item to see if its `values` member has any values in it that are not `0`:

```
data.some(item => item.values.some(v => v !== 0));
```

Comment: 1 is just an indication. It should be anything other than 0